# How to trigger custom info window programatically in Android

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I use custom window info, however, calling marker.showInfoWindow(); always renders default window info, whilst if the user clicks on the marker, custom window info are rendered without problem. Can I programatically open my custom window info?

My case is that when the markers are drawn on the map, one particular marker should show its window info (so no user interaction), but preferably a custom one, as defined in my CustomWindowInfoAdapter class.

---

EDIT, would gladly delete this question,  it was just me being clumsy, but maybe there's more guys like me out there. Anyways, my problem was that I was calling *showInfoWindow* before adding the adapter in my method *resourceRepresentationsNearBy()*, so obviously only the default info window was ever possible. So my erroneus code:

```
    private void setUpMap() {
    ...

    // Add search result markers to the map.
    resourceRepresentationsNearBy();

    // Setting up custom info window
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());

            ...
   }
```

where as, corrected code is:

```
    private void setUpMap() {
    ...

    // Setting up custom info window
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());

    // Add search result markers to the map.
    resourceRepresentationsNearBy();

            ...
   }
```

Comment: We cannot tell the mistake in your code without you showing relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Actually, just by implying with confidence that the it is related to code, you helped me. My code is trivial, so I was not counting for a mistake there. However, I was drawing markers, first, adding window info adapter after. And since I was calling showInfoWindow in my draw marker method, only default info window could open. 

I guess I should accept the answer, the moral being, always post code, or better yet, inspect more carefully. Thank you Maciej

Comment: Glad I could help. If you want to help readers in the future, edit question to put erroneous code, add an answer to show what was wrong and finally accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static GoogleMap _googleMap = null;
...


public static void initialize_google_map()
{
    _googleMap = ((MapFragment)Context.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); 

    ...

    _googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return build_info_window(marker);
        }
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {return null;}
    });


}


private static View build_info_window(Marker marker)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View custom_info_window = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);

    TextView tv_title = (TextView)custom_info_window.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
    tv_title.setText("Title");

    etc... etc...    
}
```

}

Hope it helps.