# How to add image to marker google maps api v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow, marker

I want to send image by marker to infoWindow().

```
Smaple:

    addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                           .position(latlng)
                           .title("HI")
                           .snippet("HI;HI")
               .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.same))
               .image(SampleForImage));   **// Sample what I want**
```

is that possible?

Comment: you can't add image to marker with "image()" property as marker didn't have this function?

Comment: I must to build custom Marker?

Comment: if you sinpmly want to set image of marker then you can do that with icon() function, what exactly is your requirement?

Comment: I want to add properties to Marker.
Like: Id, latlng...

Comment: Do it like this- mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, long)).title("Hello")
     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

Comment: No, I want to add properties in addition to existing ones.

Comment: in the icon() property, you set the image for marker, what else you want?

Comment: not for marker. Just keep it to another variable and use it somewhere else

Comment: have a look here: [How to trigger custom info window programatically in Android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20514671/2065594